# Long wait time of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sqlperformance

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyuR18hcm

In this URL I have shared my execution plan and query which is waiting for 5940578 ms, I got this information by using Query Store, I want to know the reason why this query is waiting for so long

Please Look into the link provided for details of the execution plan and SQL query

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any indices setup on this table?

Comment: Either you have very full pages and no disk space to make new ones, or there are triggers or other locks involved that are holding this query up, and you need to look for another blocked query somewhere.

Comment: The best solution is to optimize your indexes and another way is to disable indexes before insert and enable them after the insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just based on the plan, it looks like you have 20 indexes on that table; that seems like a lot.  Over indexing a table can add a lot of significant wait time to INSERT's and UPDATE's, particularly if the INSERT causes page splitting on the clustered index (inserting a non-sequential GUID for example).

Comment: is there any alternative for this because all those 20 indexes are also important for the database?

Comment: Performance tuning is an art and a science; I'd start by examining all of thsoe indexes to see if any of them overlap (e.g., one includes columns a,b,c and the other includes a,b; you can drop the second one).  After that, find ones you can replace with INCLUDEs.  Next, look at your insert to make sure you aren't doing page splits.   You should also make sure your maintenance plan is working.

Comment: It's complicated, but start small and test as you go.

Comment: I have applied this thing, I dropped the indexes which were overlapping but it is not effecting on performance the wait time is same even I got multiple plans in my cache after removing some indexes which were overlapping

Comment: i also want to add that I have reads as(56263(cluster),4(noncluster indx)) on only 2 indexes